# Kibana filter for equality on a field returns two documents with different field values

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

While using Kibana Discover mode, we found a concerning result.

For a given index, over a specific time range a case was found where when filtering on a field "time_stamp" (mapping to long) is equal to a specific value (1545287341), it returned two documents: one  with the exact value and another which was close.

How is this possible? The only document returned should have the specified value? What is the possible cause for this inaccurate response from elasticsearch? Would appreciate help as this is very beguiling.

I am capturing the query sent by Kibana here.

```
{
"version": true,
"size": 500,
"sort": [{
    "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
    }
}],
"_source": {
    "excludes": []
},
"aggs": {
    "2": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "interval": "3h",
            "time_zone": "Etc/UTC",
            "min_doc_count": 1
        }
    }
},
"stored_fields": ["*"],
"script_fields": {},
"docvalue_fields": ["@timestamp", "day"],
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "match_all": {}
        }, {
            "match_phrase": {
                "dev_id.keyword": {
                    "query": "22170821152"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "match_phrase": {
                "time_stamp": {
                    "query": 1545287341
                }
            }
        }, {
            "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "gte": 1544659200000,
                    "lte": 1545350399999,
                    "format": "epoch_millis"
                }
            }
        }],
        "filter": [],
        "should": [],
        "must_not": []
    }
},
"highlight": {
    "pre_tags": ["@kibana-highlighted-field@"],
    "post_tags": ["@/kibana-highlighted-field@"],
    "fields": {
        "*": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 2147483647
}
}
```

The (redacted) response showing the close-but-not-exact response is here as well:

```
 {
"responses": [{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 10,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "pkt-2018-12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "CzvHahOE1jrv+tFWGorFH4gV6cs=",
            "_version": 1,
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "time_stamp": 1.545287341E9,
                "@timestamp": "2018-12-20T06:29:01.000Z",
            },
            "fields": {
                "@timestamp": ["2018-12-20T06:29:01.000Z"]
            },
            "highlight": {
                "dev_id.keyword": ["@kibana-highlighted-field@22170821152@/kibana-highlighted-field@"]
            },
            "sort": [1545287341000]
        }, {
            "_index": "pkt-2018-12",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "PbeMWFMNpvwrjnZpBJtexDwfE9k=",
            "_version": 1,
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "time_stamp": 1.545287281E9,
                "@timestamp": "2018-12-20T06:28:01.000
            },
            "fields": {
                "@timestamp": ["2018-12-20T06:28:01.000Z"]
            },
            "highlight": {
                "dev_id.keyword": ["@kibana-highlighted-field@22170821152@/kibana-highlighted-field@"]
            },
            "sort": [1545287281000]
        }]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "2": {
            "buckets": [{
                "key_as_string": "2018-12-20T06:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1545285600000,
                "doc_count": 2
            }]
        }
    },
    "status": 200
}]
```

}

Comment: As seen from query looks like its trying to find fields time_stamp and dev_id.keyword with the specified values. The response highlights that it matched dev_id.keyword field value and returned matching documents. Bool 'must' query tries to find as many matches in the bool query as possible.

Comment: I dont get this --- its fine getting as many matches as possible, but one of the match is NOT a match. i.e. 1.545287341E9  != 1.545287281E9

Comment: Why are you using match_all in search query ?

Comment: match_phrase match text, if your timestamp is a date, it will be ignored, so the gte lte return the 2 documents in the interval.

Comment: @LeBigCat the time_stamp is mapped as long, so not a date.

Comment: @ben5556 the query is generated by the filter that apply in Kibana, I capture the query by looking at the request packet sent. What is the correct approach then?